# remove log statements using a sweet.js macro

Tags: sweet.js

I just started with sweet.js today so some problems might be easy to solve ...

I want to remove log statements from my sources for production releases. sweet.js seems to be flexible enough to do this.

There are various kinds of log statements and restrictions :

- `console.log( "wow");` should be removed whereas `console.warn( "wow");`and so should be untouched.
- `this.log( "wow");` should also be removed
- in statements like `this.assert(foo, "foo is undefined").log( "object created");` and `this.assert(foo, "foo is undefined").log( "object created").flush();` the `.log( ...)` part should be stripped out.

my current sweet.js macro including examples whats working and whats not :

```
macro console {
    rule { .log( $args (,) ...); } => { 
        // was removed
    }
    rule { _ } => { ... }
}

macro this {
    rule { .log( $args (,) ...); } => { 
        // was removed
    }
    rule { _ } => { ... }
}

macro this {
    rule { .log( $args (,) ...); } => { 
        // was removed
    }
    rule { _ } => { ... }
}

    // works
console.log( "wow");

    // works
console
.log
( "wow")
;

    // works partially -> "console." is missing before "warn" : 
    // outputs 'warn("wow");' instead of 'console.warn("Wow");'
console.warn("wow")

    // doesnt work yet
    // should output 'this.assert(foo, "foo is undefined");'
this.assert(foo, "foo is undefined").log( "object created");

    // doesnt work yet
    // should output 'this.assert(foo, "foo is undefined").flush();' 
this.assert(foo, "foo is undefined").log( "object created").flush();
```

You can play with it here : [sweetjs editor containing this example](http://sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#macro%20console%20%7B%0A%20%20%09rule%20%7B%20.log(%20$args%20(,)%20...);%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%09%09//%20was%20removed%0A%09%7D%0A%09rule%20%7B%20_%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20...%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amacro%20this%20%7B%0A%09rule%20%7B%20.log(%20$args%20(,)%20...);%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20%0A%09%09//%20was%20removed%0A%09%7D%0A%09rule%20%7B%20_%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20...%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amacro%20this%20%7B%0A%09rule%20%7B%20.log(%20$args%20(,)%20...);%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20%0A%09%09//%20was%20removed%0A%09%7D%0A%09rule%20%7B%20_%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%20...%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%09//%20works%0Aconsole.log(%20%22wow%22);%0A%0A%09//%20works%0Aconsole%0A.log%0A(%20%22wow%22)%0A;%0A%0A%09//%20works%20partially%20-%3E%20%22console.%22%20is%20missing%20before%20%22warn%22%20:%20%0A%09//%20outputs%20'warn(%22wow%22);'%20instead%20of%20'console.warn(%22Wow%22);'%0Aconsole.warn(%22wow%22)%0A%0A%09//%20doesnt%20work%20yet%0A%09//%20should%20output%20'this.assert(foo,%20%22foo%20is%20undefined%22);'%0Athis.assert(foo,%20%22foo%20is%20undefined%22).log(%20%22object%20created%22);%0A%0A%09//%20doesnt%20work%20yet%0A%09//%20should%20output%20'this.assert(foo,%20%22foo%20is%20undefined%22).flush();'%20%0Athis.assert(foo,%20%22foo%20is%20undefined%22).log(%20%22object%20created%22).flush();)

Any help is welcome :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
macro console {
  case { $console .$method( $args ... ) } => {
    return #{
      // was removed
    }
  }
}

macro log {
  case infix { . | $log ( $args ... ) } => {
    return #{
      // was removed
    }
  }
}
```

The second one is infix macro, left and right sides are separated by `|`.
Matching semicolons is not necessary.

But above macros also delete all of `warn`, `error`, `time` etc.
So I've rewritten it to this macro which complies to all conditions in the question:

```js
macro log {
  case infix { console . | $log ( $args ... ) } => {
    return #{
      // was removed
    }
  }
  case infix { . | $log ( $args ... ) } => {
    return #{
      // was removed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's brilliant easy - thanks a lot ! i added the semi colon token to your first rule for the sake of completeness. See live example here http://goo.gl/qzjAAJ